# Is it possible to use an input within a <label> field?

Tags: html, textbox, input, label

I have a bunch of optional "write-in" values for a survey I'm working on.

These are basically a radio button with a textbox within the answer field - the idea being that you would toggle the button and write something into the box.

What I'd like to do is have the radio button toggled whenever a user clicks in the text field - this seems like a use-case that makes a lot of sense.

Doing this:

```
<input type="radio" id="radiobutton"><label for="radiobutton">Other: <input type="text" id="radiobutton_other"></label>
```

works fine in Chrome (and I am guessing, other WebKit browsers as well), but there are weird selection issues in Firefox, so I'm assuming its a non-standard practice that I should stay away from.

Is there a way to replicate this functionality without using JavaScript? I have an onclick function that will work, but we're trying to make our site usable for people who might have NoScript-type stuff running.

Comment: not sure why you would need to use it inside the label; and why a radio button and not a checkbox?

Comment: Well, I don't want to use a checkbox because I have a multiple choice question that should get exactly one answer. For instance: yes, no, and other [write-in].

I was using it within the label so that the radio button would be ticked if anyone clicked within the text field - this works in Chrome but not in Firefox without JavaScript. I was hoping that there was a way to hack it to work OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting an input inside a label actually has a slightly different meaning. It doesn't make the input itself a label, it implicitly associates the label with the input in the same way as if they were linked by a `for`/`id`.

However, this only happens when the label doesn't already have a `for` attribute to override that (see [HTML4 s17.9](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.9): “When present, the value of this attribute must be the same as the value of the id attribute of some other control in the same document. When absent, the label being defined is associated with the element's contents.”). It is unclear according to spec what should happen when both containment and `for` are present.

(And also it doesn't work in IE, which makes the point moot in practical terms.)

No, you'll need some scripting for this.

```
<input type="radio" id="radiobutton">
<label for="radiobutton_other">Other:</label>
<input type="text" id="radiobutton_other">

<script type="text/javascript">
    var other= document.getElementById('radiobutton_other');
    other.onchange=other.onkeyup= function() {
        if (this.value!=='')
            document.getElementById('radiobutton').checked= true;
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It (an input inside a label) [validates](http://validator.w3.org/check) just fine as HTML 4.01.  One potential issue I can see with your code is that both radio elements have the same ID in your example.  Element IDs **must** be unique in HTML and XHTML documents and you should use the `name` attribute instead to identify a radio group.

If you are still having trouble after changing this, you will have to move the input outside of the `<label>` element and use scripting.

Comment: Both elements do not have the same id.